# Can I view the full history of google chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I want to know can I view the history log of the google chrome 
whenever I press Ctrl+H , it shows me the history but limited to a certain time.
the question is can I view the whole activity since chrome installed on the laptop ?
thank you

Answer (score 3):

Chrome saves your history only for `90 days` — and there is *no option how to change it* (as it is possible in other browsers).

But — for future — if you want keep all your history (and get other amazing tools as graphs of it or searching in it by entering search text) you may use the extension [History Trends Unlimited](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-trends-unlimited/pnmchffiealhkdloeffcdnbgdnedheme).

Or you may try singing into [Google's My Activity](https://history.google.com/history/) to see your history online.